# iOS Native Media Controller Name?

Tags: ios

I'd like to utilize this iOS native media controller in my app. See below. I just want to know what it's called so I can look it up and learn how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: hay you want o use this for sharing your content ?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, image and pdf files from an app I developed.

Comment: Now I attach the files to the messageController or mailController and send that way. This way seems much more efficient.

Comment: you can use  `UIActivityViewController` ..

Answer (score 0):

The name of the iOS controller shown above is the UIActivityViewController.